# Calculus problem with substitution

Tags: calculus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqZz9.png)

Hi, I started doing this problem and I couldn't figure out the last two question where $cos(\frac{\theta}{2})= \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$ and $sin(\frac{\theta}{2})= \frac{2x}{1+x^2}$
Could you explain to me where to start with these 2 questions. Thank you

Comment: Try drawing a triangle with opposite side equal to x and adjacent side 1

Answer (score 1):

These are trigonometric identities for half-angle formulas where in this case $x=\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$

$$\cos(\theta)=\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})-\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})=(1-\tan^2(\frac{\theta}{2}))\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})=\frac{1-\tan^2(\frac{\theta}{2})}{1+\tan^2(\frac{\theta}{2})}=\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$$

$$\sin(\theta)=2\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})=2\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})==2\frac{\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})}{1+\tan^2(\frac{\theta}{2})}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

Do you know these identities?

And please take a look at this for better formatting [enter link description here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: this does not help at all. and thank you ill read it trough